# Decompose a range in aligned blocks of size 2^n

Tags: number-theory, programming-puzzle

Given an arbitrary contiguous range of positive integers, find the decomposition in the minimum number of sub-ranges of size *L = 2^n*, with the constraint that each range must be aligned, that is the first integer *i* in the sub-range must satisfy *i = 0 (mod L)*.

Background: some (especially old) netblocks aren't a simple single CIDR, that is a range in the form 192.0.2.0/24, but are a composition of several contiguous blocks, and the whois query returns explicitly the first and last ip in the block. Try yourself with `whois 220.72.0.0`:

```
[...]
IPv4 Address       : 220.72.0.0 - 220.91.255.255 (/12+/14)
[...]
```

Solving this problem means finding the list of valid CIDR blocks that summed up constitute this range.

Comment: Are you using ^ in the exponential sense or the exclusive-or sense?

Comment: This post as it is now does not fit the description of the  programming puzzle tag at all. I think this would be better for code golf, but you need to provide some clearly defined test cases with input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

The following greedy algorithm works optimally:

> Choose the larges block allowed which is aligned with the lower bound
>   and does not exceed the total range. Add this range to your result set
>   and remove it from the search space. Loop until the entire range is
>   covered.

In the following lines I took your example and simplified it to the interesting part, i.e. take the range 72-91:

```
0)  Range: 72 - 91 (Size 20)

1a) Largest block size allowed @72: 8
1b) Subrange #1: 72 - 79
1c) Remaining: 80 - 91 (Size 12)

2a) Largest  block size allowed @80: 16 (exceeds size) -> 8
2b) Subrange #2: 80 - 87
2c) Remaining: 88 - 91 (Size 4)

3a) Largest  block size allowed @88: 8 (exceeds size) -> 4
3b) Subrange #3: 88 - 91
3c) Remaining: empty

Result: (72-79) (80-87) (88-91)
```

The structure can be seen even better, if we express the numbers in binary format.

```
0)  Range: 01001000, Size 10100

1a) Largest block size allowed @01001000: 1000
1b) Subrange #1: 01001000, Size 1000
1c) Remaining: 01010000, Size 1100

2a) Largest block size allowed @01010000: 10000 (exceeds size) -> 1000
2b) Subrange #2: 01010000, Size 1000
2c) Remaining: 01011000, Size 100

3a) Largest  block size allowed @01011000: 1000 (exceeds size) -> 100
3b) Subrange #3: 01011000, Size 100
3c) Remaining: empty
```

A note for implementation: the block size for the subrange to be chosen corresponds either to the rightmost 1 bit of the lower bound or the leftmost 1 bit of the size of the range (whichever is smaller).